# Extract data from database and embed in Mail in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to send password via e-mail to the user whenever he/she registers to my web application.I have gone through steps to send mail via Gmail in java but what i am not able to understand is How to extract that recipient's mail-id from database and pass it to the program ?
The other question is I know how to generate random password but how to embed this password in mail text.
I am using oracle 10g as Database.

Comment: Please please please do not store the password.

Comment: Store the password ???
Do you mean not send the password via mail or not store the password in database. @Vakh

Answer (score 0):

First of all as a good programmer never store store password directly in database , use MD5 encryption for store a password in database and then process further,

this is simple mail example which can help you more [Mailing using java and store before database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

and generate a random password : [random password in your form](http://syntx.io/how-to-generate-a-random-string-in-java/)

Comment: @ Janak Dhanani Ok I'll store the password in MD5 encryption but the stored password will be needed when the user will Login the application.
Whereas I need to generate and send the password to the user as soon as he\she registers in the application.
What should I do about that ?
How should I do that ?

Comment: When you want to sent a confirmation for a password in new user account at that time you can sent a password on his mail...its ohk,  but when user try to confirmation sent a system generate link for that user, and its better and good development skill to not sent a password directly...

Answer (score 0):

when user try to login in you web portal, convert a enter password filed into MD5 and now compare with database password, its enhance you security control